# GPG large file decryption duration

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg, archlinux

I want to encrypt large files on linux with a bash script. When I was looking for methods to accomplish that, I thought about GPG and gave it a try. But when I ran some benchmarks I noticed that en-/decryption of large files takes very long.

**Test scenario**
I generated a 30GB large file filled with random content. Then I encrypted it with an RSA 4096 bit key. As I understand it, GPG is a hybird-encryption programm which encrypts sessions keys with the RSA Public Key. Therefore the en-/decryption should be done wihtin seconds or at least within a minute, as it uses these session keys to encrypt the actual data, isn't it? But here are the test results - I didnt bother decrypting the file with compressen turn on as it would take me another 2 - 3 hours...

System Specs:

- GPG Version: 2.2.19
- Arch Linux
- Docker
- Intel i7

My gpg keys were generated with a config file which contained the following values:

```
Key-Type: RSA
Key-Length: 4096
Subkey-Type: RSA
Subkey-Length: 4096
Name-Real: some-key-name
Name-Comment: some-key-comment
Expire-Date: 0
Passphrase: 123456789
```

For encryption i used the following commands:

```
gpg -q --output /outputFile.txt --recipient some-key-name --encrypt /inputFile.txt (with compression)
gpg -q --output /outputFile.txt -z 0 --recipient some-key-name --encrypt /inputFile.txt (without compression)
```

This command for decrypting the files:

```
gpg -q --pinentry-mode loopback --batch --passphrase 123456789 --output /decryptedFile.txt --decrypt /encryptedFile.txt
```

**Test results**
Encryption with compression turned on:

- real 36m23.096s
- user 14m54.920s
- sys  2m31.870s

Encryption with compression turned off:

- real 21m9.781s
- user 1m39.590s
- sys  2m20.980s

Decryption with compression turned off:

- real 140m13.050s
- user 5m5.340s
- sys  16m33.020s

**Questions**
Am I missing something or am I using the tool in a wrong way?
Do you know a better way to encrypt large files with which uses an asymmetric encryption or at least uses it to encrypt the session keys?

**PS**
I googled very much and didn't find a applicable solution. I also read the man page and didn't find a hint what I might miss or did wrong. Also please be aware that I know that passing the password to gpg that way isn't the most secure way ;)

Comment: Make sure to use gpg 2.x and a CPU that supports AES-NI commands. The AES encryption/decryption and therefore the file encryption/decryption should be then much faster. See this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56167/why-is-gpg-file-encryption-so-much-slower-than-other-aes-implementations

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your answer. I updated my Question with my current system specs. I checked if AES-NI is enabled, and it is. I also already tried setting the cipher to AES256. It changed nothing :(

Comment: RSA decryption is inherently at least as slow as encryption. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57205/why-is-rsa-decryption-slow GPG is also not a particularly fast tool, so these encryption and decryption times don't seem that crazy to me. IIRC it was designed more for emails/small communications rather than filesystems/large files.

Comment: @JacobEvanShreve as I understand it (https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x209.html), private and public keys are only used to en- and decrypt the session keys which are used to encrypt the actual data. I know that GPG was not designed for that kind of purpose but I didn't find a better solution which offers hybrid encryption out of the box. Recommendations for better solutions are always welcome :)